# PHP Form fetching MySQL using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I developed a php form which initiates a database request to fetch data depending on a drop down choice.

PHP Form:

```
<form method="get" action="<?php echo $url = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
<select name="town" onchange='this.form.submit()'> 
    <?php $result= mysql_query('Query'); ?> 
<option value="x" selected>Select Choice</option>
    <?php while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?> 
        <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['town']);?>" > 
            <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['town']); ?> 
        </option> 
    <?php } ?> 
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit" /><br>
</select>
</form>
```

Form action:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["action"])) { 

$var1= $wpdb->get_results("Query");
$var2= $wpdb->get_results("Query");

Content to show once executed }


 ?>
```

How can I make the form fetch the Data using AJAX not to stay refreshing the whole page continuously but only the form part?

Comment: *"not to stay refreshing the page continuously?"* You will need to rephrase this, I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the way the form is coded now to fetch the data it needs to reload the whole page, I would like not to reload the whole page to make the execution faster

Comment: Well, you should probably [use AJAX for that](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Have you tried AJAX at all?

Comment: @putvande unfortunately I have no experience with AJAX and that is why I cam here asking help from you guys so I can have a kick start on this.

Comment: D-UH, that is what he wants US to do - use AJAX :)

Comment: Guys I'm not asking you to do my work, I'm seeking for help as I have no idea how to interact AJAX with my code!

Comment: Start with the docs: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form_id" action="<?php echo $url = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <select id="town" name="town" onchange="send_to_server()"> 
<?php $result= mysql_query("Query"); ?> 
<option value="x" selected>Select Choice</option>
<?php while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?> 
    <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['town']); ?>"> 
        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['town']); ?> 
    </option> 
<?php } ?> 
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit" /><br>
</select>
 </form>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* attach a submit handler to the form */
function send_to_server(){

var value = $("#town").val();

  /* get some values from elements on the page: */
  var $form = $("#form_id"); var url = $form.attr('action');

  /* Send the data using post */
  var posting = $.post( url, { option_value: $("#town").val() } );

  posting.done(function( data ) {
    alert('success');
  });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above does exactly what you want. Check it in localhost

Comment: You should at least do an htmlentities conversion on the PHP_SELF , as it is a known security risk (Cross site scripting).

Comment: @developers-have-no-vacation : I was concentrating more on the AJAX part as question asker wants how to get the values without page refresh. Anyways thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @MahasishShome many thanks for your code and help!!! Really appreciate. What is the best way to go about displaying html with php code in it instead of the `alert('success')` ?

Comment: @user3492795 If you want to display the value of a variable then use echo http://in1.php.net/echo & if an array then print_r  http://in3.php.net/print_r . Consider upvoting or accepting the answer if it suffices your need.

Comment: @MahasishShome the problem is that as far as I know you cannot integrate php code directly in the javascript code, that is why I asked that question or I might be wrong ?